# Is Node.js still "bleeding-edge"?

Tags: node.js

I recently watched the "Introduction to Node.js with Ryan Dahl" video on Youtube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I), and I really like the look of Node.js. Unfortunately, in that video, Ryan described Node.js as "very much a bleeding-edge technology" (in so many words), and that means it won't suit my purpose in looking at servers/server-side Javascript in the first place - to find a stable, well-supported, open-source technology to use for our server-side purposes.

I'm pretty sure that Node.js's "bleeding-edge" status hasn't change - at least not much - since March, but can anyone confirm this for me? How risky would it be to include Node.js in our design for a large (1000s of nodes), enterprise-wide system?

Thanks!
Aaron

Comment: This may have been better asked on [programmers.se] however, I will say this, the architecture is solid, it's just that things are being developed on it and around it rapidly. It's a work in progress. Keep in mind that C# is now on feature set 5, so would you say that it is "stable"?

Answer (score 3):

In general I would say "yes", but that has not stopped some cutting edge companies [from using it production](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node).  I don't know of any that are scaling ([clustering](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster)) to the level you're talking about.

I would say if you're asking here, then it probably isn't for you right now.

Comment: I disagree that if he's asking here, that it's probably not for him right now. I think it is entirely possible that it's for him.